# Enum class with type `type` as mixin

Tags: python, enums, python-class

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others) state that it is possible to make an enumeration class whose members are exactly of a certain type by adding that type as a mixin to the enum class:

> While :class:`IntEnum` is part of the :mod:`enum` module, it would be
> very simple to implement independently::
>
> ```
> class IntEnum(int, Enum):
>     pass
> ```
>
> This demonstrates how similar derived enumerations can be defined; for
> example a :class:`StrEnum` that mixes in :class:`str` instead of
> :class:`int`.
>
> Some rules:
>
> 1. When subclassing :class:`Enum`, mix-in types must appear before    :class:`Enum` itself in the sequence of bases, as in the
>    :class:`IntEnum`    example above.
> 2. While :class:`Enum` can have members of any type, once you mix in an    additional type, all the members must have values of that type,
>    e.g.    :class:`int` above.  This restriction does not apply to
>    mix-ins which only    add methods and don't specify another type.
> 3. When another data type is mixed in, the :attr:`value` attribute is *not the    same* as the enum member itself, although it is equivalent and will compare    equal.
> 4. %-style formatting:  `%s` and `%r` call the :class:`Enum` class's    :meth:`__str__` and :meth:`__repr__` respectively; other codes (such
>    as    `%i` or `%h` for IntEnum) treat the enum member as its mixed-in
>    type.
> 5. :ref:`Formatted string literals <f-strings>`, :meth:`str.format`,    and :func:`format` will use the mixed-in type's :meth:`__format__`
>    unless :meth:`__str__` or :meth:`__format__` is overridden in the
>    subclass,    in which case the overridden methods or :class:`Enum`
>    methods will be used.    Use the !s and !r format codes to force usage
>    of the :class:`Enum` class's    :meth:`__str__` and :meth:`__repr__`
>    methods.

I was trying to make an enum whose members were types (objects of type `type`), but since `type` is a special class (it is a metaclass more than a class), I'm getting a bunch of errors like argument mismatch for `mro`, `__new__`, `__init__`, etc:

```py
import enum

class A: pass

class B: pass

class C(B): pass


class MyTypes(type, enum.Enum):
    SPAM = A
    EGGS = C
```

Example of error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file>", line 10, in <module>
    class MyTypes(type, enum.Enum):
  File "<file>", line 182, in __new__
    dynamic_attributes = {k for c in enum_class.mro()
TypeError: descriptor 'mro' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

I realise this might be an XY problem, so I'll explain my concrete example. In a card game I'm developing, I have a `Card` class hierarchy; each of the subclasses represents a different card type. However, the mapping between card types in the game and subclasses of `Card` might not be 1-to-1; for example there might be some intermediate abstract classes that serve as an implementation help but that do not represent an actual card type.

So I want to make an enumeration that contains all of the game card types, and I want the members to be the actual concrete subclasses implementing those types, so that I can easily interoperate enum members and the actual classes: the idea is to access class attributes, instantiate them, etc without having to use `.value` every time (as in some cases I might have to work with something that is either a member of the enum or the class itself).

Comment: Even if this turns out to be possible, the semantics of the resulting enum members would be far too confusing. A different design would be a better idea.

Comment: In your example, you reuse the key `EGGS`, this lead to an error.

Comment: @Anakhand: Those work the other way around. You can have `FOO=1` and `BAR=1`, but not `FOO=1` and `FOO=2`.

Comment: Aliases is another name for the same value, not the same name for two values

Comment: Ah you are totally correct, for some reason I had that flipped in my mind. I've corrected the example. In any case, that's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is not currently possible to mix in `type` to an enum.

---

The purpose behind mixing in data types is two-fold:

- ensure that all members are of that type

```
class Number(int, Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 'three'
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'three'
```

- make the members directly usable as that type

```
class Number(int, Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
Number.ONE + 2
# 3
```

As you noted, `type` is not a data type -- it is a metaclass.  It would need special support to work.  What is your use-case?

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I realise this might be an XY problem, so I have explained my concrete use case in an edit to my question.